# Prophet "Jeremiah" from Tanach in translation to German language online available?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet, translation, yirmiyahu--book-of

These days the story of the prophet Jeremiah caught my deeper interest. Currently reading it in various German translations of the Bible I see that it might be non-trivial how near to the original the translation is, so I started to compile a side-by-side synopsis of three main versions ("Luther (1984)", "Einheitsübersetzung", "Neue evangelische Übersetzung") But I have not been successful to find a German Tanach-version of it.

> ***Q:*** Where can I find an online version of the Tanach in German translation? (at least the book of the prophet Jeremiah)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_German

Comment: @doubleAA: I could not recognize a link to a version of the Tanach (by Mendelssohn for instance, or by Buber) - links to Luther's and others christian translations are known to me. At talmud.de there is only "Kohelet" (and so on with other problems ... of non-existence and shortcomings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/1090985) you can download a german translation of the Tanach by (Reform Rabbi[[1]](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9F)) Dr. [Ludwig Philippson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Philippson) from [here](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/download/pdf/1090985?name=Die%20Propheten).

Comment: Is it a translation based on (little-_o_) orthodox Judaism?

Comment: Not a clue - it's all I found online. I've asked my (distant) family living in Germany; they discovered all their Tanach's were translated into English! They are asking around if there are any into German - I'll update ethe answer as soon as I get an answer - if I ever do.

Comment: Upps, a late acceptance. Don't know why I 've forgot "accepting" your answer. Perhaps because I'd found the tanach-translation by Philippson and immediately started reading. :) Sory for that impoliteness!