# Jeremiah 23:33 - "burden"?

Tags: words, translation, yirmiyahu--book-of

I have difficulties to understand the German term *"Last"* or *"Lastwort"* in the common [Christian](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Jeremia23%2C33) German translations of Jeremiah chap 23, verse 33 (corresponding to *"burden"* in [English versions](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1123.htm#33)). Thanks to a link in an answer, I've found a [German translation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44017/1569) of the Tanakh by [Prof. Philippson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Philippson), and he uses something like "...was ist der '*Auftrag des Ewigen*'..." ("I don't give you *tasks/jobs*")

I don't have an idea of a good English representation, which has the connotation that I get when I'm reading the Philippson's text, but reading this gives me a much better, smoother and immediate understanding than the *"burden"*-versions.

Since this also agrees better with my own spiritual so-to-say structure, I would like to know, whether Prof. Philippson's translation was more appropriate compared to translations containing *"burden"* or similar words.

See below a screenshot from the Philippson's translation:

[image: picture]

Comment: You expect us to be experts in German (a language that I speak to a limited extent), but this is a Judaism site. You should somehow rephrase your question (in order to avoid being closed as off-topic), that how the word מַשָּׂא is interpreted in [Jeremiah 23:33](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1123.htm#33).

Comment: @Kazibácsi - thank you for your remark. Well, the question is induced by the german translation, but I would be satisfied when this would be explained as well in english only. I feel a big difference between saying "burden" and saying "give tasks". My problem here is that I'm not sure about a good english word for the german "auftrag" with its specific connotation, otherwise I could reduce my question completely into english. I ask here on mi-yodeya since it might be significant that Prof. Philippson is a genuine jewish source and I thought that it might be the more correct translation at all.

Comment: @Kazibácsi - ah, I followed your link, and see the "burden"- word as well. So I assume the answer to my question is simply, that the Philippson's version is missing-the-point?

Comment: As I saw now, most Jewish sources agree that the word should be interpreted here as _burden_ (see [Rashi on the verse](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16020/showrashi/true#v33)). If you look up the occurrences of the word in a concordance, you'll find this very clear usage as _burden_ in [Exodus 23:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0223.htm#5), but [Numbers 4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0404.htm) is also talking about a similar concept. So I'd also go for _Last_ instead of _Auftrag_ (if that matters).

Comment: @Kazibácsi - thank you again. I followed the link to the Rashi-comment and I think I'm going to understand the point, the comments there should help. Maybe need a bit more time and chewing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hebrew word משא literally means a 'burden', but is often used in the Prophets to mean a prophecy, and specifically a negative prophecy of a burden some nation will be made to bear.

The classical commentator Rashi explains on [Jeremiah 23:33](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.23.33?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) (link is Hebrew, this is a loose translation)

> 'What is the burden of the Lord' - This was said as a jest, since they found his prophecies burdensome.

This usage is also found in Isaiah, e.g [Chapter 17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.17.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and in other places.

Comment: Thanks, simyou, for the answer. The comments really help to change mind towards the more common translation. Perhaps I should leave the Philippson's translation aside, I've looked at it studying Kohelet and Ezra/Nehemia and some other texts and maybe it's sometimes misleading as well.

Comment: @Gottfried In general it's good to see different commentaries and translations, as in many cases there are indeed debates about interpretation, but it doesn't seem to be such a case.

Comment: @Kazibácsi - again thanks for the remark! Just to "close-the-case" here: should I edit the question? (Or maybe you've an immediate idea: just feel free to improve it accordingly)

Comment: @Gottfried, simyou, I think Rashi's point is that this is a pun. They'd go to the prophet and ask him ~"any new prophecies lately?" but do so using the word "משא" to show that his messages were burdensome.

Comment: @msh210 - you made me smile :) I'll take it as another facet!

Answer (score 0):

שד''ל אומר ככה

והמתרגם האלכסנדרי והיירונימוס תרגמו כאלו כתוב במקום את מה משא: ׳אַתֶּם הַמַשָּא׳

והסכים בזה

Ludovicus Capellus.

והוא מתיישב יפה עם ונטשתי אתכם

וכפירוש רש״י

https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Shadal/Yirmeyahu/23.1#m7e0n6